# Segmentation of 2D data with additionally categorical variable

Tags: python, image-processing, cluster-analysis, image-segmentation

there's a segmentation problem that I would like some help with.
I am trying to segment a large set of points in 2-Dimensional space, that also has one categorical variable. The primary segmentation should be done by clustering of the spatial data and, if necessary, the clusters should then be further divided based on the categorical variable.

Here's an example:
Let's say we have a dataset of geographical coordinates of houses in a city. In addition to the location of each house we also know which colour it has. If we would plot the location of the houses and the colour they have we would get the image below. You can see there are three neighbourhoods in this town, two of which are geographically difficult to separate but are clearly distinct based on their looks.

[image: Picture of three clusters. One is clearly separate, the other two border but can be separated based on colour (green on one side, orange and purple on the other]

The above example would be difficult to segment with a clustering algorithm like DBScan or K-means, which would not take into account the categorical variable. In addition we cannot separate the purple and orange houses, because both can be found in the same neighbourhood. It would also be difficult to cluster in multidimensional space with gower's distance, because that might lead to houses with odd colours being assigned to clusters outside of their geographical confines.

What would be a good approach to this problem? Are there any python (or R) implementations of clustering algorithms that could deal with this sort of problem? Or would a computer vision approach be more fitting?

Any input would be welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at mean-shift segmentation?

Comment: I just looked into it and it looks interesting. Would it work with clusters of mixed categorical values though? Also, am I correct that this would probably mean that the categorical value needs to mapped back to a continuous variable?

Comment: you would need to apply some mapping to your categorical data. but AFAIK meanshift can allow you to treat the "categorical" dimension(s) in a different way than the spatial domain. So, if you have three categories, you can map it to a binary 3-vector (ending up with 5D data).

Comment: This sounds like a good approach, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to run, say, DBSCAN separately for all subsets of colours, obtaining a large set of putative neighbourhoods, and then to take the minimal elements of this set, with respect to set inclusion.

In the above example:

- green gives you the south-west,
- blue, red, and blue+red give you the
  north and the south-east,
- green+red/blue/both give you the north and
  the south (a merge of two correct neighbourhoods) and then you filter
  out the south by taking the minimal elements.

Comment: Hi Felix, thank you for the suggestion. Intuitively this was also my first approach but the set inclusion complicated the analysis and also tended to oversegment the image. I'm still working on refining this approach to perform better, but was interested in alternative strategies.